# Error Installing ruby runtime in Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber

I try to install ruby runtime, rvm, cucumber plugins in Jenkins,

When I am installing ruby runtime plugin, I meet this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1328)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1126)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install ruby-runtime plugin
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:487)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1324)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to initialize
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.load(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:441)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:478)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCircularityError: org/jruby/RubyClass
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    ...
```

How to fix it? Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's a known [bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31019).
There is a workaround:

in `/etc/default/jenkins`

```
-Dhudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.noBytecodeTransformer=true 

JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -Dhudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.noBytecodeTransformer=true"
```

At the moment there is no definitive solution as you can see.

Comment: Thank you so much! I installed Jenkins in windows. Where can I find these files? I just uploaded a screenshot of my Jenkins folder structure in the question above.

Comment: I thinks it's jenkins.xml in Windows but I'm not sure (did not try it on windows). Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: I am running Jenkins as a Tomcat war file. Where can i implement this workaround?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows,
Adding argument

```
-Dhudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.noBytecodeTransformer=true
```

in **jenkins.xml** file worked for me as @lvthillo stated.

```xml
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -Dhudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.noBytecodeTransformer=true -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8081 --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
```

Comment: This is not working for me :( Windows Server 2019 and Jenkins 2.277.1

Answer (score 1):

On OSX I had to edit `/Library/Application Support/Jenkins/jenkins-runner.sh`

to add these lines at a point after `javaArgs` was defined

```
# workaround for ruby runtime install issue
# per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883551/error-installing-ruby-runtime-in-jenkins
javaArgs="$javaArgs -Dhudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.noBytecodeTransformer=true"
```

There is probably a more mac-ish way to do this.

Upon rebooting Jenkins, the ruby runtime plugin, which was already downloaded, started working, as did the also-downloaded rvm plugin, which is the one I was after.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing java version to 8th.
Maybe there is a problem with java 11 compatibility issues.
1- https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-java-8-on-centos-7/

2- On Centos delete all *ruby plugin* in `/var/lib/jenkins/plugins`

3- download ruby-runtime.hpi plugin from https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/ruby-runtime/

4- Upload Plugin in jenkins `/pluginManager/advanced`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-Dhudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.noBytecodeTransformer=true` in `jenkins.xml` file doesn't work for me (Windows, Jenkins 2.277.1).

So I just deleted all files for `ruby-runtime` from `Plugins` folder (you need to shutdown Jenkins service) and start Jenkins again.

Answer (score 0):

For me, installing `java 8` solved the problem. After that I was able to install the `ruby-runtime` plugin.

Environment:  `Debian 10`

Comment: It should be `ruby` though.